# Change logo theme according to important events/holidays?

Tags: discussion, logo, design, events

Similar to Google, but with some important differences:

- It will be more like adding stuff to the logo, instead of making the logo out of stuff
- The changes should not take away your attention for more than 2-3 seconds
- The logo colors and text should never be altered

So basically, the changes will only be like *adding* stuff to the logo (e.g a pumpkin in Halloween)

Do you think modifying the logo according to important events or holidays will bring more positiveness than negativeness to the site?

**Edit:** we should use the visitors ip location to display relevant holidays to maximize positiveness (or to be more specific, minimize the negativeness)

Comment: Who gets to choose the events/holidays? A significant number of our readers are from outside the U.S. And what types of events? Do we want the same brouhaha as when one of the Tech Gliterati died and there was a special banner put on the site, but when another member of the Tech Gliterati died there was nothing?

Comment: @AlEverett that will be a problem, one solution to this it to only show the changes specific geographic location using the ip of visitors

Comment: -1 this only serves to enrage the politically challenged. *"Omigerd you left out Important Day X you insensitive clods!"*

Comment: We have our [own way](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115764/50049) of recognizing certain holidays that doesn't involve altering sprite maps or making additional browser requests. It's just a bit more subtle than what you describe.

Comment: @Tim Post: Enlighten us.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basing this on geographic location sounds like a lot of work.

To start, there'd be a one-time investment from a dev to write code to serve different logos and possibly CSS depending on visitor IP.

The real issue is that someone would have to constantly keep track of which holidays/events were coming up in which countries, including things that don't simply recur every year based on date.

Also, as sixlettervariables [said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135176/change-logo-theme-according-to-important-events-holidays#comment376756_135176), Meta will end up fielding a steady stream of posts like

> "Omigerd you left out Important Day X you insensitive clods!"

Doesn't seem worth the effort, for the small amount of benefit it would provide. Not to mention that page loads would slow down, although I don't know if the effects would be noticeable.

Comment: For what it's worth, I do generally like it when sites put up custom themes for special events. I just don't think it's worth it for Stack Exchange to do so.

Comment: very true, sounds a lot of work and won't fit well in here.

Answer (score 7):

I definitely agree with Al Everett's comment above:

> Who gets to choose the events/holidays? A significant number of our readers are from outside the U.S. And what types of events?

Therefore the only reasonable option is:

[image]

Comment: What, no horn on the jack o lantern to at least _recognize_ the first day of the fourth month .. and on *meta* at that? You insensitive clod!